# Extract Columns from file and print to new file with delimiter Shellscript

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I want to print the 1,2,3,6 the columns of a delimited file with the same delimiter. The delimiter is 1e(hex) or 036 (octal). This is bashscript. I read from posts that my attemp was a good way to do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\036"} {print$1,$2,$3,$6}' filename > newfile.txt
```

When I do this, the file contains everything from the source file. Looking to see what I did wrong. Below I have some sample input and output. The actual file has many records. The ^^ is a representation of 1e(hex) or \036(octal).

Input:

```
Q001^^bob123^^001^^X^^ ^^^^ ^^               ^^TX^^B^^ ^^   ^^2^^10
```

Output:

```
Q001^^bob123^^001
```

Comment: Please post sample Input and expected output in code tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OFS` is the *output* field separator, not the *input* field separator. You have to set `FS` as well.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\036"} {print$1,$2,$3,$6}' filename > newfile.txt
```